# Nuget paths are different after csproj upgraded

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, csproj

I am trying to upgrade my WFP project from the VS 2015 format to the new VS 17 format. There is a lot of trial and error involved but I have come across an issue which I can find no solution for online:

Some of my code is looking for a file in a certain location:

```
name C:\git\myproj\packages\A.B.C.Installer.4.1.7\setup\dbpkg\MyProj.dbpkg is invalid.'
```

Unfortunately the new nuget places the same file in:

```
C:\git\myproj\packages\a.b.c.installer\4.1.7\setup\dbpkg\MyProj.dbpkg
```

It does two things different:

1. everything is lowercase
2. instead of appending the version, it create a new directory

How can I configure the nuget client to behave like it did before? I am unable to change my code to match.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT No resolution. I had to keep with the old .csproj format since nuget cannot be configured.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure the nuget client to behave like it did before? I am unable to change my code to match.

I am afraid you have to update your code. That because this is the expected behavior now for the new NuGet.

> Package ids and versions are case insensitive in NuGet and are now
>   written out lowercase to the global packages folder to avoid conflicts
>   on case sensitive file systems.

You can check some more details info from following thread:

[NuGet PM 3.5.0 incorrectly using lowercase path in *.nuget.targets](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3840)

So, if you update your project to the new VS 17 format, you have to update you code to resolve this issue. I saw you saying that you are unable to change my code to match, but this change was designed to make nuget work better, there is no ticket for us to return to the past at this moment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This in combination with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/known-issues#changing-the-capitalization-of-nuget-package-ids-breaks-package-restore took me so much time :(. Maybe this should be better known? that packages should default to lowercase from a certain nuget version?